# Inserting custom html in wordpress and make it editable

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello guys I'm just wondering if there is a plugin that will help me to insert my custom html page in wordpress and make it dynamically editable. I'm just new in wordpress and have no idea on doing this. I've googled already on how to do this but it lacks information what I need. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Why would you like to insert the HTML page, instead create a page from backend, and add content to it.

Comment: because i'm inserting a page with parallaxing effect and i want the page content is editable sir.

Comment: well that wouldn't be feasible I guess, you gotta create a Wordpress page, write the style and JS again. You can't just directly import the static pages into WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

[Insert HTML Snippet](http://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-html-snippet) WordPress plugin is the solution, It Adds HTML, CSS and JavaScript code to your pages and posts easily.